# DuckDuckGo does not work correctly through Tor

Tags: connection, browsers, troubleshooting

When I link to [DuckDuckGo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckDuckGo) from the Tor Browser it always comes up without the menu bar for DDG. This results in me not being able to change the settings, 
consequently it is always loaded with search set on strict.

Any ideas?

Hell there is no reason to even have tor if DDG will only let me search for kid books and recipes...

Hope someone out there knows what's up.

P.S. my sequence is to open Nord VPN/Tor/DDG.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest that you try the onion address for DuckDuckgo?  :

https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/

It's what I use and find it well, cleaner in the way it presents itself. Also, and I don't know if it will make a significant difference on your end, my input is that perhaps you may not want to use NordVpn, or any VPN in the onion network. If for no other reason, it may be slowing down packet handling across the network due to "double encryption".

You can always enable your VPN (which you definetely need in windows) once you are done with using the Tor network.

Just a couple of thoughts.

Cheers, Harold C.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you're using the non-javascript version of Duckduckgo.

To fix this simply disable NoScript for Duckduckgo.

If you want to find out which version of DDG you're using, watch out for the url. If the url contains `/html/` then you're using the html version.